# Ubuntu РРTP (без менеджеров)

Tags: ubuntu

Сбил настройки РРTP соединения с провайдером, он был настроен без менеджеров (через консоль). Хотелось бы узнать:
1) Как настроить РРTP подключение к провайдеру без использования менеджеров.
2) Как подключится к РРTP VPN.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

В общих словах — пишете конфиг PPP-подключения в `/etc/ppp/peers/`. Для PPTP отличие от остальных PPP будет в опции «`pty "pptp` *адрес_сервера* `--nolaunchpppd"`». Пример конфига (комментарии мои):

```
noipdefault           # Сервер задает свой адрес по IPCP
defaultroute          # Добавить маршрут по умолчанию
replacedefaultroute   # Заменить маршрут по умолчанию, если уже был
usepeerdns            # Получить DNS-сервера от сервера
pty "pptp vpn.example.org --nolaunchpppd" # Собственно, PPTP
remotename "provider" # Имя удаленной системы
name "username"       # Имя пользователя
noauth                # Не требовать у сервера аутентифицировать себя
refuse-pap            # Запретить PAP (небезопасно)
refuse-chap           # Запретить MS-CHAPv1 (небезопасно)
persist               # При обрыве «перезвонить»
maxfail 0             # Перезванивать до бесконечности
holdoff 30            # С задержкой в 30 секунд, чтобы не злить провайдера
```

Все опции подробно описаны на man-странице [`pppd(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pppd).

Атрибуты доступа прописываются в `/etc/ppp/chap-secrets`. Например:

```
# username    remotename    password
#
"username"    "provider"    "topsecret"
```

Дальше поднимаете соединение используя `pon` *`[имя-peer'а]`*. Т.е., если создавали файл `/etc/ppp/peers/provider`, то и поднимается `pon provider`. Дальше можно прописать в `/etc/network/interfaces`, например, так:

```
auto provider
iface provider inet ppp
    provider provider
```

Логи будут идти в syslog (процесс `pppd`), прочитать можно `plog`. Если не взлетает — для лучшей отладки добавляем в опции (peer-файл) строчку «`debug`».